# Function "DATE" not found; SQL statement:

Tags: java, mysql, h2

When I was using MySql database for my webproject, If i run the query `SELECT Date(now())` gives me the current date.
Recently while running some unit-test I decided to use in-memory `H2 database` for better performance. And now if I use the query `SELECT Date(now())`, it gives me the following error

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "DATE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT Date(now()) [90022-178]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readJavaFunction(Parser.java:2326)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFunction(Parser.java:2378)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:2712)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2244)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2231)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2201)
```

So how do I use **MySql functions in H2 database**

Answer (score 4):

With H2, you need to use the `CURRENT_DATE` function instead of what you're using.

[CURRENT_DATE](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_date)

As others noted, there's standard SQL and some extensions to it (which are different in the different RDBMS providers/vendors). The `CURRENT_DATE` is part of the standard, the `DATE` function is not. So just use the standard function and you will be fine with both H2 and MySQL.

Comment: In that case I need to change my code a lot of place any alternative without changing in the bulk amount of code?

Comment: @M.Sharma MySQL itself also [supports `CURRENT_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date), and it is in the SQL standard, better to fix it once than to continue living with legacy incompatibilities

Comment: Is there any other way if I want to use Date() instead of anything else

Comment: No, H2 just doesn't have the `DATE` function.  If you want code that works in more than one database, it's best to use ANSI SQL only.

Comment: H2 allows you to create user-defined functions with the `CREATE ALIAS` syntax and to provide your own Java implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is the sort of difficulty you face when swapping databases. Although JDBC and most SQL statements will be compatible, you will have trouble with built-in functions which vary between database vendors.

There are some approaches to solve this:

1. Put all SQL statements into an external resource such as a properties file, and have unit tests load a different resource. That way production code will see the MySQL statements and Unit-test code will see H2 statements.
2. Just use MySQL. Don't worry about performance, unit tests are not performance-critical. Use a framework such as [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)
3. Don't involve the database at all in unit tests. Since JDBC itself is not under test, you can assume it works and instead mock it with a framework such as [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)

Answer (score 0):

You should run H2 in MySQL [compatibility mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) (= MySQL dialect) without altering your current SQL queries.

**EDIT**:

> So how do I use MySql functions in H2 database

As for the support of the `DATE()` function, you could use `CREATE ALIAS` and provide your own implementation. Read under [User-Defined Functions and Stored Procedures](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) for an example, it's quite straightforward.

There's also [this old thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/kziTTTNlB9o) on the H2 discussion board on this topic with an implementation of [MySQL date functions](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/tools/org/h2/mode/FunctionsMySQL.java), but do read the thread to see how to use them.

Comment: Compatibility Mode does not provide support for inbuild functions